# How to ignore with nodemon everything except a folder and an specific file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, nodemon

I have this folder structure

```
.
├── admin/
│   └── ...
└── services/
    ├── user/
    │   ├── main.js
    │   └── model.js
    └── post/
        ├── main.js
        └── model.js
```

And this script in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "admin": "nodemon src/admin/ --exec babel-node",
  },
```

I want to restart the process only when something inside **admin/** changes or when a file called **model.js** outside of the admin folder changes.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a `nodemon.json` file in the root of your project and then add the folders/files to watch in the `watch` property. `nodemon.json` will be used as the [config](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files) for nodemon. You can also ignore files/folders as well.

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "services/*.js",
    "services/**/*.js"
  ],
  "watch": [
    "admin/*",
    "model.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This was my solution without the nodemon.json

`"admin": "nodemon src/admin/ --exec babel-node -w src/admin/ -w src/**/model.js",`